# CURL post form doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, curl

i am using PHP Version 7.1.9 and i have problem with submitting form via CURL. 
In my index.html i want via AJAX show response of a form, which is on page form.html using CURL.

index.html

```
 function sendForm() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "formHandler.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {
                showResponse.html("");
                showResponse.append(response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                showResponse.html("");
                showResponse.append(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

Form.html is pretty simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    name:
    <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</html>
```

Handler of a form is simple too, only show submited data and just for secure write it in txt file.

form.php:

```
<?php
$name=$_POST["name"];
    echo "hello $name";
$myfile = fopen("log.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "$name";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

formHandler.php:

```
<?php
// add form data
$data = array();
$data['name'] = 'SuperUser';
$post_str = '';

foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    $post_str .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';
}
$post_str = substr($post_str, 0, -1);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/form.html');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Now the problem is, when i use `sendForm()` i doesn't see submitted form (`form.php`), but only unsubmtited form (form.html). First i thought, that's CURL only doesn't showed a submitted page, but log.txt is also empty. It can be because of PHP version, or is there other problem? In my `phpinfo.php` i have got **cURL** support enabled with version 7.55.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to submit to form.php, not to form.html. What form.html does from a browser is done by formHandler.php using Curl

This line should be changed

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/form.html');
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/form.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have the function sendForm() but is been not called at any place.

I think, on form submit you may require it to call this.

Tell me your requirement, so I can help with this code.

And also in form.php, fix the below line

```
$txt = "$name";
```

as

```
$txt = $name;
```

For PHP variables you don't need to give double quotes

Comment: I implemented sendForm() to button in index.html. Anyway thanks for a help.